# Sending GET cros request from unity to laravel 8 on Nginx

Tags: unity-game-engine, nginx, laravel-8

Im currently developing an api with laravel 8, Nginx as web server.
but the request is getting blocked on server side.

here is my unity code

```c#
  public IEnumerator MasterJsonDownload()
    {
        request = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://localhost:8000/GetMaster");

        request.SetRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        
        request.SetRequestHeader("Method", "GET");
        
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        if (request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
        {
            JsonLoad(request.downloadHandler.text);
            _isFinished = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError(request.error);
        }

    }
```

here is Nginx conf setting

```
access_log /dev/stdout main;
error_log /dev/stderr warn;

server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/kinoko_server/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    # set client body size to 1024M #
    client_max_body_size 1024M;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        if ($request_method = 'GET') {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header Content-Type text/plain;
            add_header Content-Length 0;
            return 204;
        }


        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

on laravel side, I added *fruitcake* by composer and made sure to add it to the 1st line of Kernel.php $middleware array

cros.php is present and only changed this value

```
'exposed_headers' => ['*'],
```

then I include the header with my response

```
return $json_data
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');;
```

the response is working on browser, but it is getting blocked if I made it from unity.
I`m still learning and I might have forgotten a step.

by the way, I`m using docker to build up my environment.
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btGfP.png)